# Deep routing in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create routing in angular 2 with below scenario

home.component:

```
    @RouteConfig([
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: HomeComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/route1/:id',
            name: 'Route1',
            component: Route1Component
        },
        {
            path: '/route2/:id/...',
            name: 'Route2',
            component: Route2Component
        }
    }]
```

Route2.Component:

```
    @RouteConfig([
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Route2Home',
            component: Route2HomeComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/edit',
            name: 'Route2Edit',
            component: Route2EditComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/details/:otherId',
            name: 'Route2Details',
            component: Route2DetailsComponent
        }
    }]
```

home.html is having few links with router Links.

1. Home link: `<a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>`
2. Route1 link: `<a [routerLink]="['Route1', {id: 'id'}]">Route1</a>`
3. Route2 home link: `<a [routerLink]="['Route2', {id: 'id'}]">Route2 Home</a>`
4. Route2 edit link: `<a>Route2 Edit</a>`  How to configure routerLink for this?
5. Route2 details link: `<a>Route2 details</a>` How to configure routerLink for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Route2', 'Route2Edit', {id: 'someValue'}]"]>Route 2 Edit</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Route2', 'Route2Details', {id: 'someValue'}]"]>Route 2 Details</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. My bad. That is issue with copy paste. But how to set the parameters to  '/route2/:id/...' and '/details/:otherId'  these two parameters need to set in routerLink isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working. earlier i tried with ['/Route2', , {id: 'someValue'}, '/Route2Details']"] // i.e one slash at the beginning of the inner route path.

Comment: I don't know if it matters at which position the parameters are passed. The `/` at the beginning is only necessary if the routerLink is not in the root component AFAIK. After the first route is specified to start on the root `/` then the following routes have to be direct child routes anyway and they should start where the previous ends (no `/`)

Comment: Make sense. And about the position of the parameters. If i change the order of the parameters then giving some console error. For details link route i have mentioned as  [routerLink]="['/Route2', , {id: 'someValue'}, 'Route2Details', , {otherId: 'someValue'}]". Then it is mapping the right params with right route path. Thanks.

Comment: If this fixes your issue please accept the answer to indicate your problem is solved (using the white checkmark below the up-down-vote buttons)