# Issue in nested routing in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a scenario where I need to load a menu which is built using angular2 routing. Inside a particular component I need to load another menus/tabs which is nothing but a another angular2 routing component. Please find the snapshot of my requirement [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ebRJ.png)

Please find the code for main menu

```
import {Component, bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, RouteParams, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {ComponentOne} from '../Dashboard/Dashboard1';
import {ComponentTwo} from '../Dashboard/Dashboard2';
import {ReportOne} from '../Reports/Report1';
import {menutopbar} from './menutopbar';
import {leftmenu} from './leftmenu';
import {Clicksenselink} from './clicksenselink';
import {ManageRedisCache} from '../Admin/ManageRedisCache';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp-menu',
    templateUrl: './Menu.html',
    directives: [menutopbar, leftmenu, ManageRedisCache, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
   // providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
        { path: '/Dashboard1', name: 'ComponentOne', component: ComponentOne },
        { path: '/Dashboard2', name: 'ComponentTwo', component: ComponentTwo },
        { path: '/Report1', name: 'ReportOne', component: ReportOne },
        { path: '/Clicksenselink', name: 'Clicksenselink', component: Clicksenselink },
        { path: '/ManageRedisCache/...', name: 'ManageRedisCache', component: ManageRedisCache}
])

export class componentmenu {
    constructor() {
        console.log("componentmenu component being called");
    }
}
```

Please find the code for the child component which internally loads another routing component

```
import {Component, bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, RouteParams, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';   


import {Extractor} from './Extractor';
import {ExtractorQueue} from './ExtractorQueue';
import {Schedule} from './Schedule';
import {DefaultComponent} from './DefaultComponent';


@Component({
    template: `
<div class="container">
    <h2>Redis Administration</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="[ 'ExtractorQueue']">ExtractorQueue</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab"  [routerLink]="['Schedule']">Schedule</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
</div>
`,
    directives: [Extractor, ExtractorQueue, Schedule, RouterOutlet]
})

    @RouteConfig
        ([
    { path: '/', name: 'Default', component: DefaultComponent},
    { path: '/Extractor', name: 'Extractor', component: Extractor, useAsDefault: true},
    { path: '/ExtractorQueue', name: 'ExtractorQueue', component: ExtractorQueue },
    { path: '/Schedule', name: 'Schedule', component: Schedule }
])

export class ManageRedisCache
{ }
```

When I run my application I am getting the following exception in the chrome console

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("s Administration</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="[ 'Ext"): ManageRedisCache@4:48
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property (" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="[ 'ExtractorQueue']">ExtractorQueue</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab"  [routerL"): ManageRedisCache@5:33
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("="tab" [routerLink]="[ 'ExtractorQueue']">ExtractorQueue</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab"  [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['Schedule']">Schedule</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
"): ManageRedisCache@6:34 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseExceptionconsoleError @ code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js:487
code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js:489 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:(…)consoleError @ code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.16/angular2-polyfills.js:489
```

any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: tried with the following link suggestion, but still it didn't work  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542732/deep-routing-in-angular2          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" [routerLink]="['/ManageRedisCache', 'Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" [routerLink]="['/ManageRedisCache', 'ExtractorQueue']">ExtractorQueue</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" [routerLink]="['/ManageRedisCache', 'Schedule']">Schedule</a></li>
       
    </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update to ng2-rc ... anyways , read more https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html

to have nested routing you need to add 3 dots

```
{ path: '/ManageRedisCache/...'
```

and have a default route in ManageRedisCache

```
 { path: '/', name: 'default', component: default},
```

and add `routeroutlet` directive in ManageRedisCache

Comment: what is the default here? I am getting compilation error for default variable. should i need to create a component for this?                               { path: '/', name: 'default', component: default},

Comment: yes or you can use any current component and add router-outlet too

Comment: i created a new default component and tried, still the issue exists..i have posted/edited the new code.. please let me know what other changes to be done ?

Comment: bdw which version of angular2 ?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },

Comment: 2.0.0-beta.17 , thats too old , before moving ahead with your app i suggest you should upgrade to rc2 , there are lots of breaking changes but update yourself , anyways router rc is not released yet so for router the same syntax can work for few days only.

Comment: now first level menu is loading, but the links are not working i.e. hyperlinks are not clickable...updated the error message in the post

Comment: add  { path: '/', name: 'default', component: DefaultComponent, usedefault:true}, and compile and check

Comment: getting error like below:       Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("s Administration</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="[ 'Ext"): ManageRedisCache@4:48
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property (" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['Extractor']">Extractor</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="[ 'ExtractorQueue']">ExtractorQueue</a></li>

Comment: thanks...it is working fine now. i am accepting the answer..thankyou very much...

Comment: if possible can you help me with this issue? even I am struck with this issue for long...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736268/not-able-to-consume-external-webapi-service-from-angular2-service

Comment: welcome but update to latest version , for that question have you bootstrapped http_providers??